# Eleatic arguments (argumenta Eleatica)?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, history, philosophy-terms

I want to know how to say "Eleatic arguments" as well as how to say "Eleatistic arguments". Right now, all I can come up with for the former is "argumenta Eleatica", and I have no clue about the latter. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I don't know what either of these terms mean or whether there is a canonical translation, but I would render the first one like you did and the second one as *argumenta Eleatistica*.

Answer (score 4):

"Eleatica" indeed seems to be the correct way to refer to the "Eleatic school," founded by Parmenides.

[This book](https://books.google.com/books?id=bZSadbNlnTgC&pg=PA62) includes on pg. 62 a section titled, *De Secta Eleatica*.

Although I can find no written examples in medieval or modern Latin of *eleatistica* (by which I presume you mean "Eleatic-imitating"), I think a convincing analogy can be made with the more common terms "Hellenic" (*hellenica*) and "Hellenistic" (*hellenistica*). The same transformation yields *eleatistica*.

You thus have:

> Argumenta eleatica

and

> Argumenta eleatistica

Comment: For Modern Latin, this is undoubtedly correct, but have you checked out the textual issues with the ancient evidence? The passages referring to the Eleatics in Cicero appear corrupt.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer Even without the Cicero reference, the two others in this classical [corpus search](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=%23eleatic) seem to support it. Either way, it would be a question of whether that word was used, not how it should be formed.

Comment: I'm not disputing the formation, I just found the confusion fascinating. I know at least the passage in *Academica* was corrected, I wonder if others show sign of corruption in the manuscripts.